# Flutter CustomClipper Triangle

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, clipper

I have this triangle  [image]
and a i would like that its shape would be like this [image]

Can someone help me ?
this is my actual code

```
class TriangleClipperr extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(TriangleClipperr oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: your code seems ok. what widget do you wrap your ```TriangleClipperr``` with? seems like the problem derives from the size from parent widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to move the current point to middle, then draw rest path.

```dart
class TriangleClipperr extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width / 2, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(TriangleClipperr oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Shape depends on parent size.
[image]

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can check [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-custom-clipper-28c6d380fdd6) for more.